Angular 17 build chunks - post build scripts, alter HTML
I have made new angular project in v17.3.0 - SSR mode enabled.
Below is the image of ng build output
build output
I can see in index.html , that 3 chunks are added with modulepreload (chunks in Initial Chunk files)
<link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-KFDVPRYR.js"><link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-WFAJ4VF6.js"><link rel="modulepreload" href="chunk-LDGDJR6O.js">

network tab resources load
I want to understand what these 3 files are for.
Now, i want to remove the modulepreload option to increase my LCP. Currently i am preloading my images, but its still being fetched after these 3 scripts are done loading.
So, i wrote a post build script and moved all my preload links(eg. ) before all the links(rel="modulepreload").
The issue is after page load its giving error: Error: NG0507(https://angular.io/errors/NG0507). The content was altered as in the position of links tag are moved. How to resolve this issue.
Can some one please guide me on this.
What i expect to happen is , my preload links should execute first than the chunks preloadmodule
Latest Update:
Based on this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/27581 , we can remove the preloadmodule chunks from angular.json. we have to add preloadInitial as false. After adding its working how i want. Its resolved.
"index": {
"input": "src/index.html",
"preloadInitial": false
}

If you are using something like Cloudflare, disable the HTML auto optimization option in order to prevent content removal that angular depends on for hydration. 
